# How to add two textViews to custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

i tried to add two textViews to list item.that data get from list. when the list print, it display correctly. But in list view its not print correctly. Can anyone help me?

This is the custom adapter class.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final String text1 = listData.get(0);
        final String text2 = listData.get(1);


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.ratings_list, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        lblListHeader1.setText(text1);

        TextView lblListHeader2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        lblListHeader2.setText(text2);

        return convertView;
    }
```

This is the activity code.

```
public void ListDrwaer() {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("ratings");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String restName = jsonChildNode.optString("rest_name");
                listData = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (restName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String userName = jsonChildNode.optString("user_name");
                    String rate = jsonChildNode.optString("rate");
                    String ratOut = "Rate :  " + rate;

                    listData.add(userName);
                    listData.add(ratOut);
                    Log.d("Data", userName + rate);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error..." + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        RatingsAdapter adapter = new RatingsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                listData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I want to add user name, below of that it's rate.

This is should be the output list.

```
01-23 11:59:09.102: D/Data(4873): omali  3.5
01-23 11:59:09.102: D/Data(4873): sunil  2
01-23 11:59:09.102: D/Data(4873): kuma@fh.com  1.5
01-23 11:59:09.102: D/Data(4873): fhhhy@ghj.com  0.5
```

Comment: The details what you have provided is not very clear, could you please post your xml file.

Comment: @anuruddhika try my ans

Comment: take a look at my answer, i think all the other forget the fact that you are creating a new list in every iteration. Also, you avoid a double sized list, and all the other methods will be simpler and safer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the way you are building the list, it will never work, since you are deleting it and creating a new one in every iteration, so when you create the adapter,  in the listyou only have the last item.

I would do:

```
ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> listData = new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>(); //added


public void ListDrwaer() {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("ratings");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String restName = jsonChildNode.optString("rest_name");
                //removed listData = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (restName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String userName = jsonChildNode.optString("user_name");
                    String rate = jsonChildNode.optString("rate");
                    String ratOut = "Rate :  " + rate;


                    listData.add(new Pair<String,String>(userName,ratOut ));//added
                    //removed listData.add(userName);
                    //removed listData.add(ratOut);
                    Log.d("Data", userName + rate);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error..." + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        RatingsAdapter adapter = new RatingsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                listData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Then, in the custom adapter class, you retrieve that data simply by

```
@Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             //only this 3 lines change
             Pair<String,String> item= listData.get(arg0);
        final String text1 = item.first;
        final String text2 = item.second;


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.ratings_list, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        lblListHeader1.setText(text1);

        TextView lblListHeader2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        lblListHeader2.setText(text2);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always printing the wrong data, regardless of the **position** of the item

```
final String text1 = listData.get(0);
final String text2 = listData.get(1);
```

So Better take the Different lists of the **username** and **ratOut** and display the data

```
final String text1 = userNameListData.get(arg0);
final String text2 = ratOutListData.get(arg0);
```

Here **arg0** is the position

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
   final String text1 = listData.get(arg0*2);
    final String text2 = listData.get(arg0*2+1);
```

and override:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listData.size()/2;
    }
```

As you are adding both the text in one `arraylist` 0,1 belong to first item and 2,3 belong to 2nd and so on.

Also size of the list view item would be half of the size of `arraylist`.

Try this.

also change this:

```
   listData = new ArrayList<String>();//<--out side for loop

 for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String restName = jsonChildNode.optString("rest_name");
                if (restName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String userName = jsonChildNode.optString("user_name");
                    String rate = jsonChildNode.optString("rate");
                    String ratOut = "Rate :  " + rate;

                    listData.add(userName);
                    listData.add(ratOut);
                    Log.d("Data", userName + rate);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes i tried. but it only display only the last user data of the list ne. i want to display all user data in arraylist

Comment: check my edit, put  listData = new ArrayList<String>() out side for loop. for each iteration you are creating a new arraylist and adding only one item to it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
final String text1 = listData.get(0);
final String text2 = listData.get(1);
```

with:

```
final String text1 = listData.get(2*arg0);
final String text2 = listData.get((2*arg0)+1);
```